# Changing background image on modal in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have 2 pages, one home page the other one is modal. Modal has its own background, but how can I change modals background by clicking something on the homepage?

modal.html

```
    <ion-content>
something here
    </ion-content>
```

modal.scss

```
.scroll-content {
    background-image: url("image.jpg") !important; 
}
```

home.html

```
<div class="circle" (tap)="openModal1($event)">
    </div>
```

home.ts

```
tapMiddle(e) {
    this.openModal1();
}
```

So basicly, when someone clicks on a div, it is supposed to open the modal and change the background. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the background by changing the style.backgroundImage property. You can change the imageUrl as you like on the button click event and you should be good.

```
<div [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + imageUrl + ')'">
```

Comment: Yes, but how to change it?

Comment: I guess modal is another page in ionic, then you can pass a parameter to the modal page when user click on the button and according to it you can assign the value of imageUrl variable in modal page's controller. 
You can refer the below link if you want to know how to pass parameters between pages.
http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-2-beginner-navigating-between-pages/